# Add a permanent NSDictionary to ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, nsdictionary

I am building a Railway app for iPhone. The app lists some Train Stations around the user in one of the views. But I don't want to always ping the server, for accessing data that will not change. What I intend to do here is, to create a dummy application and access the Stations List once, save it in an `NSDictionary` and then copy that `NSDictionary` file permanently to my real app. How can I do that?
Note:- Using `Objective-C`. NOT `Swift`

Comment: You can use Core Data or archive it to disk.

Comment: you can use Database, Text file or property list in iOS

Comment: I'm confused by one little bit `"What I intend to do here is, to create a dummy application and access the Stations List once, save it in an NSDictionary and then copy that NSDictionary file permanently to my real app."` So you want to create 2 apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store your data in archive using NSUserDefault. and Update data after some time period `ex. every 2 hour` or whatever.

**Store Data**

```
NSData *datadic = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourDictionaryName];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: datadic forKey:SCHEDULEDATA];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**GET Data**

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:SCHEDULEDATA]!= nil){
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:SCHEDULEDATA];
    NSMutableDictionary *yourDictionaryname = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]; 
}
```

Use **yourDictionaryname** Every time..Thats it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any one of below for storing..

**NSUserDefaults** -- It is used for saving data temperarily.

**Core Data** -- It is used for saving large data with more Different Types of records.

**Property List** -- Plist.

If u want to save data permanently even the app is deleted from Device.

You can use below UIKeyChain for Getting the data after deleting and re-Installing the app also. This case will not work with Core Data & User Defaults..

**KeyChain store** will store data by accessing KeyChain Access.

https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore

Hope it is useful content..

Answer (score 0):

If the list of stations never change or you don't want to support updates on-the-fly and you simply just want the list baked into your app, another approach could be to include a json file in your app. You can then simply retrieve the content from the file by:

```
NSString *stations = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stations" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```